# Laravel Query n+1 - Querying custom attribute relationship count

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.8

On my User model I have the following...

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough
 */
public function transactions(): HasManyThrough
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Transaction::class, Product::class);
}

/**
 * @return int
 */
public function getNumberOfOrdersInLastSevenDaysAttribute()
{
    $weekAgo = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
    return $this->transactions()->whereDate('transactions.created_at', '>', $weekAgo)->count();
}
```

When I get all Users using my custom attribute even eager loading *transactions* I get an n+1 issue.

[image]

What options do I have to omit my n+1 problem?

Comment: You must be get `transactions` relations when getting initial resource. Fore example `Model::with('transactions')->get();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're eager loading the `transactions` relation, but the `getNumberOfOrdersInLastSevenDaysAttribute` method doesn't actually use the loaded relation. It writes a new query using the `transactions()` definition as a base. You can update the method to return a relation instead of the count and then use the [`withCount`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) method to load the count.

```
public function ordersInLastSevenDays()
{
    $weekAgo = Carbon::now()->subWeek();
    return $this->transactions()->whereDate('transactions.created_at', '>', $weekAgo);
}
```

Then to load the count and access it.

```
$user = User::withCount(['ordersInLastSevenDays'])->first()
$user->orders_in_last_seven_days_count
```